# Create a view from data in the same table using different Where clause

Tags: sql, view

I need to create a view using data from 1 table where it all has a different where clause.  I'm using employee time records to report on projects.  I have separate views that work for each column but I'd like to combine them into one view if possible without creating multiple views and joining them.  So I have something along the lines of project#, time worked, time billed, time status, time pay rate, time bill rate.  Time status shows billed or not billed.  So I have a query of Project, (time worked * time pay rate) AS Work Cost, then Billed by project, so Project, (time billed * time bill rate) AS Billed amount WHERE time status = billed, then so on and so on, all with different WHERE clauses.  I'd like one view that eventually shows Project, Work Cost, Billed Amount....  Is this possible without creating a view for each where clause and then combining those views into one final view?

Comment: You may want to post data sample and the desired query result based on this sample data set.

Comment: What is your RDBNS (SQL *flavor*)?

Comment: Actually, yes. You would need to go with CTE. sorry aboout above